# WCF - The maximum array length quota (16384)

Tags: wcf, exception, wcf-binding

When I receive files I receive this exception.

My client configuration:

```
 <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>

      <binding name="basicHttpSecuredBinding"
               maxReceivedMessageSize = "2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
              <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
      </binding>

</basicHttpBinding>
```

Client endpoint

```
<client>
      <!--TODO: currently configured to work with the staging for testing-->
      <endpoint name="ep_SmtkSyncService"
               address="https://1234.com/SyncService.svc"
               binding="basicHttpBinding"
               bindingConfiguration="basicHttpSecuredBinding"
               behaviorConfiguration="transportWithClientCredentialsBehavior" 
               contract="SynerionHcm.Smtk.Domain.Common.Contracts.ISmtkSyncService" />

    </client>
```

This exception has driven me crazy:

```
The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.'.  Please see InnerException for more details. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type
```

Comment: Is this your service or your client configuration? Do you actually apply the binding to your service and client?

Comment: @CodeCaster added endpoint

Comment: You need to apply the same config to your service.

Comment: Ok, where it could be? It's a legacy project and I'm new to WCF

Comment: @CodeCaster is this the same configuration or it's should be on Azure?

Comment: What version of .NET are you on?  Do you have an endpoint defined in your service config?

Comment: check your server config, make sure you have maxArrayLength value set to appropriate value in server side as well